# Почему способы образования слов так называются?

Tags: словообразование, названия

Названия способов образования слов вызывают некоторые сомнения, например: лексико-семантическое, лексико-синтаксическое, лексико-морфолого-синтаксическое словообразование.

Какое значение в этих названиях имеет элемент "лексико-", нет ли здесь повтора, например: лексико(= словарно)-синтаксическое словообразование?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исходя из того, что лексика - это словарный состав, а слово зачастую состоит из нескольких, 
как, например, "чревоугодничество", "паровоз", "словообразование", наконец, со спокойной душой можно давать подобные названия.  "Лексико-морфолого-синтаксическое" словообразование. Здесь лексика - состав, морфа - форма, синтаксис - порядок. Упорядоченный состав форм. "Лексико-семантическое" - смысловое значение состава слов, т.к. семантика - это суть, значение. И так далее.

Comment: Лексика - "отнесенный к слову", словарный запас языка, морфология - раздел языкознания, изучающий части речи и их грамматические признаки, синтаксис -  раздел лингвистики, изучающий строение словосочетаний и предложений, семантика - это значение. Вот, к примеру, слово "наконец" образуется на основе словосочетания предлога и падежной формы существительного. Это лексико-синтаксический способ словообразования. Почему нельзя сказать просто:"синтаксический способ словообразования" (на основе словосочетания)?

Comment: Но есть, оказывается, морфолого-синтаксический способ: "заведующий" - переход причастия в существительное. Только непонятно, что там "синтаксического". Такое впечатление, что названия придумывали люди без фантазии, пользоваться ими совершенно невозможно.

Comment: Смотрите, София, вы пишите "синтаксис - раздел лингвистики, изучающий строение словосочетаний и предложений", и в то же время предлагаете:"синтаксический способ словообразования". Что получается?- Способ - это некая заданная закономерность, правило, в данном случае синтаксическое, из чего следует, что синтаксис не только изучает, но и задаёт, формирует, организовывает. Как вы считаете, существует в ваших словосочетаниях алогичность, или нет? Мало кто вникает в суть своих же слов до конца и отсюда рождаются подобные спорные определения.

Comment: С синтаксисом у нас все в порядке: синтаксис изучает словосочетания, словообразование способом сращения словосочетания можно назвать синтаксическим. А вот аффиксацию лучше бы называть морфематическим способом ( а не морфологическим), потому что морфология изучает части речи. Тогда переход прилагательного в существительное и был бы морфологическим способом. Основной принцип орфографии (сохранение морфемного состава)называют морфологическим, хотя это морфематический принцип (сейчас уже встречаются оба названия). Такая вот у нас морфемика-морфология получается.

Comment: А знаете, что на самом деле меня слегка огорчает? То, что исследователи русского языка в своих работах стараются оперировать как можно большим количеством нерусских слов, делая этим свои труды малопонятными, спорными и труднодоступными.